# Cancel retrofit request when using it with coroutine flow

Tags: retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I have retrofit interface like below:

```
@GET("products")
fun getProducts(
    @Query("limit") limit: Int,
    @Query("offset") offset: Int
): Flow<List<Product>>
```

I'm calling this method like below:

```
restService
    .getProducts(limit, offset)
    .flowOn(ioContext)
    .catch { /* handle error */ }
    .collect { /* handle result */ }
```

This code snippet could be called in situations:

1. When pulled Swipe refresh
2. When loading the next portion of data.
   That's why I want to cancel the previous request before making a new one. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is to run the collection in a coroutine that gets cancelled when the data is not needed anymore. It can be as part of a flow. An example:

```
combineTransform(limitFlow, offsetFlow, refreshSignal) {
    emitAll(restService.getProducts(limit, offset))
}.collect { }
```

(here refreshSignal would emit whenever a refresh is needed).

The flow returned by `getProducts()` will be cancelled each time new values are emitted from the input flows.

You could as well cancel the collection manually, keeping the job and calling cancel on it.

```
val getProductsJob = launch {
    restService
        .getProducts(limit, offset)
        .flowOn(ioContext)
        .catch { /* handle error */ }
        .collect { /* handle result */ }
}
```

... then you can cancel that job whenever you feel like:

```
getProductsJob.cancel()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I see that it could help. Is this only possible way how to achieve this?

Comment: No, it's up to you how you decide how to cancel the collection. You could as well do it manually, keeping the job and calling cancel on it. I'll add that to the reply.